# Failed to find module: "nativescript-angular/http", relative to: app/tns_modules/

Tags: android, nativescript, tns

I'm using NativeScript 6.1.1 with Angular 8.0 and I did have the 'tns preview' going at some point, but now when I try to run 'tns preview' and use my Samsung Galaxy S8 (Android 7) I get this error

```
Successfully sent initial files for platform android.
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1209)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1096)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1083)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-angular/http", relative to: app/tns_modules/
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:56)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:151)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1063)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1055)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:20)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
LOG from device Galaxy S8: and...
LOG from device Galaxy S8: android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
```

I've tried refreshing everything with;

```
rm -rf node_modules platforms hooks
npm i
tns run android
tns preview
```

That didn't help. It works in the emulator. I tried to use http-client instead but it wouldn't start. I've updated to the latest packages and that too didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Angular 8 `@angular/http` is removed so `nativescript-angular/http`.

You must [migrate](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) to `NativeScriptHttpClientModule`